# Associating an account with a set of data

Tags: python, tkinter, pickle

```
DCprice = 100
ACprice = 10
FCprice = 500
TCprice = 5000
Gold = 0
Multiply = 1
autoclickers = 0

def SaveGame():
    with open('objs.pickle', 'wb') as f:
         pickle.dump([Gold, DCprice, Multiply, ACprice, FCprice, TCprice, Multiply, autoclickers], f)

def Load():
    with open('objs.pickle', 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)
```

This is my code for saving data from my Game.
What I would like to know is, how I would assosiate an account with each peice of data. So for

([Gold, DCprice, Multiply, ACprice, FCprice, TCprice, Multiply, autoclickers],

Would be saved within one Account with would have a username and password.

So my question: I have no idea how to do this, any hint in the right direction would be nice

Answer (score 1):

Create an `Account` object. This is exactly what classes and objects are for:

```
class Account(object):
    def __init__(self, username, password, dc=0, ac=0, fc=0, tc=0, gold=0, multiply=1):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.dcPrice = dc
        self.acPrice = ac
        self.tcPrice = tc
        self.gold = gold
        self.multiply = multiply
```

The first time you run your code you can create a couple accounts:

```
accounts = [Account("joe", "secret"), 
            Account("sally", "password", gold=100)]
```

If you want to set the amount of gold in account 0 to 1000, you can do it like this:

```
accounts[0].gold = 1000
```

You can pickle and unpickle the `accounts` array since it's made up of simple datatypes. For example:

```
with open('objs.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(accounts, f)
```

Comment: Why is gold in there? is it required? (in the accounts dict)

Comment: @Csarg: I'm just guessing at what you want to associate with an account. You can put anything you want in the object.

Answer (score 0):

You could dump a data structure like this:

```
data = {
  'username': username,
  'password': password,
  'account_info': [Gold, DCprice, Multiply, ACprice, FCprice, TCprice, autoclickers],
  }
```

Or, for multiple accounts:

```
data = [{
  'username': a.username,
  'password': a.password,
  'account_info': [a.gold, a.dcprice, a.multiply, a.acprice, a.fcprice, a.tcprice, a.autoclickers],
  } for a in accounts]
```

Then, just dump and save that object:

```
pickle.dump(data, f)
data = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: What about "logging" into or "acessing" the account defined?

Comment: Actually, I like Bryan's answer better.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can store your data in a database, like MySQL. All you would have to do is set up your table and use a connecter to allow you to insert the data into your table. For instance, with MySQL:

```
import mysql.connector
mysql.connector.connect(user='', password='', host='', database='')
INSERT INTO table_name values (Gold, DCprice, Multiply, ACprice, FCprice,
TCprice, Multiply, autoclickers)
```